# SSRSReport Report Mvc Viewer Problem Because Small Rectangle Box Problem

Tags: model-view-controller, reporting-services, report

[My Report Builder Scree Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3GWr.png)

[My Project Viewer In Small Box Problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUxHN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have made ssrs report in that have not add any box  , when i run in my project there showing 2 box , i have attached both screenshots .